# The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am a newbie to MongoDB and I am trying to use aggregation functions

I am surprised that the following lines of code work:

```
db.country.aggregate(
[
     {$project: {_id:0,
                 name:1,
                 size_of_language: {$size: ["$language"]},
                 size_of_ethnic: {$size: ["$ethnic_group"]}
                }
     }
])
```

It gives me the number of languages and ethnic groups in each country.

However, after I try to make them equal, I get an error, i.e., the following lines of code

```
db.country.aggregate(
[
     {$project: {_id:0,
                 name:1,
                 size_of_language: {$size: ["$language"]},
                 size_of_ethnic: {$size: ["$ethnic_group"]}
                }
     },
     {$match: {$expr: {$eq: ['$size_of_language', '$size_of_ethnic'] } }},
])
```

gives me an error

*MongoServerError: The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: string*

Any ideas why? Thank you so much!

Comment: Would be helpful if you can give a sample document. The error message suggests that something is wrong with the field `language` or `ethnic_group`

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually, you have reminded me of something! There might be some data points that contain '' instead of arrays in the fields and thus that code produces an error!

Comment: But I am still surprised that the bug does not appear in the first snippet of code. Interesting....

Comment: "It gives me the number of languages and ethnic groups in each country." - no it does not. You pass `{$size: ["$language"]}` which constantly returns 1, no matter of the content. As already mentioned, some sample data would be useful. Consider operator `$isArray`